# convert qtablewidget item to float

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I Have a Qtablewidget , and a signal cellchanged(), that calls a Slot Change();

```
setup_ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(1);
setup_ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem("Gain");
setup_ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0,item);
QTableWidgetItem *item1 = new QTableWidgetItem("Offset");
setup_ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1,item1);
```

However , i couldn't convert the cell edited value to float, something like

```
setup_ui->tableWidget->item(0,0)->float();
```

Please help,

Comment: can you add code about creation, connection and so on ...

Comment: I need to assign the edited text of cell from tablewidget to float variable. I tried reinterpret_cast<float*>&(setup_ui->tableWidget->item(0,0)->float()) , but it dint work  out

Comment: i hope my answer helps

Answer (score 3):

what you need within the slot

```
Class::Change( int row, int column ) {
  bool ok
  float value = setup_ui->tableWidget->item(row, column)->text().toFloat(&ok);
  if (ok) {
    // do whatever with value
  }
  else {
    // do some error handling
  }
}
```

You can skip the flag (bool ok) if you can guarantee that the conversion never fails!

**For more info, post more code ...**

Comment: Thank you so much , but it gives an error "" Base operand of ->pointer has non pointer type Qstring""

Comment: i corrected it - text() returns QString, so you need `.` instead of `->`

Comment: I tried either , but the application hangs at this point, when I tried using debug mode.

Comment: you should create a small example without the designer => just a `QWidget` with the `QTableWidget`, then you can post the class with the code you created